# how remove gnome builder and all its artifacts

Tags: gnome-builder

I installed gnome builder to try it out. Didn't like it and uninstalled it. However its artifacts remain---in particular my main system menu is now transparent. I hate it when a newly installed application changes your settings and makes itself a default application without asking.